# I cannot add additional libraries with premake5

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, static-linking, premake

I am learning OpenGL and GLFW, and I decided to use premake5, because it seems easy to use and maintain. My project is located in a folder called **LearningOpenGL**. I am on MAC.

> Project structure.

- LearningOpenGL

  - src

    - Application.cc
  - vender

    - GLFW

      - include

        - GLFW

          - glfw3.h
          - glfw3native.h
      - lib-macos

        - libglfw3.a
- premake5.lua
- vender

  - bin

    - premake

      - premake5

*Application.cpp*

```
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(void)
{
GLFWwindow* window;

/* Initialize the library */
if (!glfwInit())
    return -1;

/* Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context */
window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Hello World", NULL, NULL);
if (!window)
{
    glfwTerminate();
    return -1;
}

/* Make the window's context current */
glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

/* Loop until the user closes the window */
while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
{
    /* Render here */
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    /* Swap front and back buffers */
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);

    /* Poll for and process events */
    glfwPollEvents();
}

glfwTerminate();
return 0;
}
```

*premake5.lua*

```
workspace "LearningOpenGL"
    configurations { "Debug", "Release" }

outputdir = "%{cfg.buildcfg}-%{cfg.system}"

project "LearningOpenGL"
    kind "ConsoleApp"
    language "C++"
    targetdir ("bin/" .. outputdir .. "/%{prj.name}")
    objdir ("bin-int/" .. outputdir .. "/%{prj.name}")

    files { 
        "%{prj.name}/src/**.h", 
        "%{prj.name}/src/**.cc"
    }

    -- including GLFW headers
    includedirs "%{prj.name}/vender/GLFW/include"

    -- linking with GLFW
    libdirs "LearningOpenGL/vender/GLFW/lib-macos"
    links "libglfw3.a"


    filter "configurations:Debug"
        defines { "DEBUG" }
        symbols "On"

    filter "configurations:Release"
        defines { "NDEBUG" }
        optimize "On"
```

When I do

```
vender/bin/premake/premake5 gmake
```

> Building configurations...
>   Running action 'gmake'...
>   Generated LearningOpenGL.make...
>   Done (36ms).

and then

```
make
```

from Terminal it gives me this error which I cannot solve.

> ==== Building LearningOpenGL (debug) ====
>   Linking LearningOpenGL
>   ld: library not found for -llibglfw3.a
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
>   make[1]: *** [bin/Debug-macosx/LearningOpenGL/LearningOpenGL] Error 1
>   make: *** [LearningOpenGL] Error 2

*Also, are there other easy to use project managers that I can use instead of premake?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be:

```
links "glfw3"
```

or

```
linkoptions "-llibglfw3.a"
```